# Getting error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

Tags: c#, readline

I'm new to coding. I am trying to improve myself by making simple coding. I just encountered such error while writing a code to retrieve data from user.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FuelCalc
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //readline
            Console.WriteLine("Lütfen size hitap edebilmem için adınız ve soyadınızı giriniz...");
            string namesurn= Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Merhaba " + namesurn +" lütfen aracınızın ortalama yakıt tüketimini giriniz...");
            int yakit = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may find the [int.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-6.0) method helpful. `Console.ReadLine()` is going to return a `string`… you can use the try-parse method to convert it to an `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could try is adding a loop to repeat until the user enters a number. The [int.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-6.0) method will return `true` if the string returned from `Console.ReadLine()` can be interpreted as an `int` and you will have a value for `yakit` in that case. Otherwise, ask the user to try again.

(I'm relying on Google Translate here leave me a comment if I did something wrong!)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //readline
    Console.WriteLine("Lütfen size hitap edebilmem için adınız ve soyadınızı giriniz...");
    string namesurn = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Merhaba " + namesurn + " lütfen aracınızın ortalama yakıt tüketimini giriniz...");

    // Loop until a valid int is received.
    while(true)
    {
        if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int yakit))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{yakit} alınan");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Numara gerekli");
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

You may want to consider `float` or `double` instead of `int` in case the user enters a decimal point character like "40.9" in which case you could substitute:

```
float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out float yakit)
```